# Overlapping divs using bootstrap extend past page width, unsure what the cause is

Tags: html, css

I have some divs arranged in a way so that there are two columns, and a box that overlaps between them. For reasons I can't figure out, the div extends just slightly past the page width, causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear (which is bad).

Additionally, the left most div extends below the background image of the parent div, which should not be possible.

Why are these divs not lining up neatly?

My HTML code is below. I am not using a snippet as the snippet shows the output in responsive mode which does not demonstrate the issue. I know that inline CSS is advised against, and it is only used for the purpose of this question.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Demo Page</title>

</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

<div style="height:500px;background-image:url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg);background-position:center;background-size:cover;">
    <div class="row pb-3" style="height: 520px; position:relative;">
        <div class="p-3" style="position:absolute; background:white; top:100px; height:220px; width:400px; z-index: 2;">
        <h1>Text to overlap here</h1></div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background:grey;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-9" >&nbsp;</div>
        
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to row with class pb-3

```
.pb-3{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

You can also add to div with class p-3

```
.p-3{        
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using "height" and use min-height /max-height instead.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you provided code example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).